# Group columns of a SQL query into an array

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

I have the following `SQL` query:

```
SELECT Date AS timestamps, Seasons1 AS seasons_1, Seasons2 AS seasons_2,
    Seasons3 AS seasons_3, Seasons4 AS seasons_4, Seasons5 AS seasons_5,
    Seasons6 AS seasons_6, Seasons7 AS seasons_7
FROM SeasonsTable WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY timestamps DESC
```

Is there any way to return a **single column** (called say `seasons`) that contains all the `seasons_*` as an array?

For example, this currently returns:

```
timestamps seasons_1 ... seasons_7
2019-04-28 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
```

but I'd like it to return:

```
timestamps seasons
2019-04-28 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

Comment: (1) Your code is not MySQL code.  (2) SQL does not have an "array" type.

Comment: Does SELECT date, seasson1+' '+seassons2+' '+... suffice?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks and I've updated the tags. A bit of a newbie here.

Comment: You are going to have to add the sql dialect you are using and the version.

Comment: @apomene I get `Error converting data type varchar to float.`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: @jarlh Thanks and yes, `MS SQL Server`

Comment: @alex_lewis: Instead of `seasson1 + ' ' + seassons2 + ' ' + ...`, where the `+` assumes numerical context and therefore tries to upcast the spaces, try to use `concat(seasson1, ' ', seassons2, ' ', ...)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The SQL standard of 2003 does in fact have array types. They're just not supported by the most widely-used databases, except Postgres. It's Feature S091.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, TSQL doesn't have arrays.
To return the data as a delimited string you just need to join the columns:

```
SELECT Date AS timestamps, Seasons1 + ',' + Seasons2 + ',' + Seasons3 + ',' + Seasons4 + ',' + Seasons5 + ',' +  Seasons6 + ',' + Seasons7 AS season
FROM SeasonsTable WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY timestamps DESC
```

Dependent on the datatype of your seasons columns you might need to use cast(seasonsX as varchar) rather than just the column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Date as timestamps, '[' + cast(Seasons1 as nvarchar) + ',' + cast(Seasons2 as nvarchar) + ... + ']' as seasons
```